# "sudo: unable to initialize PAM: Critical error - immediate abort" when try to run "sudo apt-get update" on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, sudo, authentication, error-handling, pam

I am encountering an issue on my Ubuntu system when attempting to run the command `sudo apt-get update`. The terminal returns the following error message: `sudo: unable to initialize PAM: Critical error - immediate abort`. I am seeking assistance in resolving this problem.

I have already attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Rebooting the system.
- Running the command with the `-i` option.
- Checking and updating the PAM configuration files using `sudo pam-auth-update --force`.

Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue.

At this point, I am unsure of what else to try. Any guidance or additional troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You can `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` to see what was logged in the last 5 minutes. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** In order to better diagnose your issue, please edit your question directly with the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks